# Generar un wait en navegador con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, navegador-web

estoy intentando automatizar una pagina web utilizando el motor gecko, es similar al webBrowser que trae incorporado Visual Studio. Estoy usando el evento

```
navegador.DocumentCompleted += (senderx, ex)=>
```

Para esperar que se complete la pagina, me va bien con todo menos un input que a veces me lo rellena y a veces lo pasa de largo, lo leo de la siguiente manera

```
Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement input = (Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement)document.GetElementsByName("txtorderNo")[0];
input.SetAttribute("value", "aKl8_Sbl");
input.Value = "aKl8_Sbl";
```

Para evitar que lo saltee quiero hacer una pausa, el tema es que estoy teniendo problema con eso, pobre distintas cosas y nada me funciona

- Los metodos IsBusy y IsAjaxBusy siempre me devuelven false
- El "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep" no me sirve porque me frena la carga del navegador asi que es como si nada
- Usando este codigo me hace la espera pero me a el siguiente error.

  > {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: index"}

  ```
  public void Esperar(int tiempo)
  {
      DateTime reloj = DateTime.Now;
      reloj = reloj.AddSeconds(tiempo);

      while (reloj > DateTime.Now)
      {
          Application.DoEvents();
      }
  }
  ```
- Los otros dos que use son estos pero tampoco me funcionan

  ```
      async Task Delay()
      {
          await Task.Delay(100000);

      }

      public void Wait(double seconds)
      {
          Timer timer = new Timer();
          timer.Interval = (int)(seconds * 1000);
          timer.Tick += (s, o) =>
          {
              timer.Enabled = false;
              timer.Dispose();
          };
          timer.Enabled = true;
      }
  ```

Si alguno tiene alguna respuesta espero pueda ayudarme, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y cómo indica [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22158489/1468942) podrías hacer una `async Task` bastante parecido a lo que ya tienes:

```
async Task PutTaskDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
} 

private async void btnTaskDelay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PutTaskDelay();
    MessageBox.Show("I am back");
}
```

Fíjate que se llama a la función con un `await` y que la función que **lo llama tiene que ser `async`**

Comment: async Task Delay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100000);

    }

Ya indique que lo había usado pero no me funciono, no espera el proceso de carga

Comment: Entonces el problema tiene que estar en otro lado... ¿seguro que lo llamas con un `await`? Si es así tu problema no está en "esperar" a que acabe de procesar.

Comment: `async Task Esperar (int segundos)
        {
            segundos = segundos * 1000;
            await Task.Delay(segundos);
        }`
Despues de tanto luchar me funciono, me estaba faltando poner el async al metodo private async void RellenarFormulario(). Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el codigo que comentas falla porque compara con todos los valores de tiempo de los DateTime que llegan hasta milisegundos, aunque, no comprendo bien porque se produce, o cual es el desfase fuera de rango. Si limitas la comparación a los segundos, puesto que el valor de la espera es en segundos, no falla.

```
    public void Esperar(int tiempo)
    {
        DateTime reloj = DateTime.Now;
        reloj = reloj.AddSeconds(tiempo);
        while (reloj.Second > DateTime.Now.Second)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

**- Nota : Tu mismo me dijiste que el error se sitúa en el metodo esperar.
Y lo que me vengo a referir, es que en el while tenías puesto While (reloj > DateTime.Now), lo cual no compara un segundo con el segundo actual, sino
un milisegundo, con el milisegundo actual.. mientras que el retardo, trata
de ocupar X segundos (y no milisegundos). Por otro lado, no creo que Application.DoEvents(); sea para nada el origen del error, pues lo que eso hace, es revisar y actualizar el control de los demás eventos, evitando que haya eventos no controlados, o que no se actualice correctamente la interfaz de la ventana por este motivo; Por ello creo que Application.DoEvent(); es muy conveniente para que la asignación que comentas se complete adecuadamente, especialmente si has observado que llegó a asignarse al usar ese metodo. Hay errores que se producen, porque un hilo de proceso en la aplicación, se accelera más que la actualización de control eventos, y, revisando los demás eventos, puede evitarse el error.**

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que ya estoy usando el evento "navegador.DocumentCompleted += (senderx, ex)=>". Y se ve que hay algun inconvenient con el Application.DoEventes();. Si te fijas estoy siempre trabajando con segundos, en el metodo reloj.AddSeconds(x);